# How to create a custom Ubuntu image

Tags: linux, ubuntu

It'd be very useful for my team to have an Ubuntu image (.iso) with some softwares and repositories already added in.

For example we would need MongoDB already installed (http://bit.ly/OWklPQ) as well as Sublime Text and Elasticsearch.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to just do it manually once and then have it ready next time we need a new machine.

Comment: probably you can run a shell script to add the repository location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [ubuntu builder](https://code.google.com/p/ubuntu-builder/), you can use it for mint, too.

Answer (score 0):

http://alllinuxstuff.blogspot.in/2012/07/five-tools-to-build-your-own-ubuntu.html around 5 great tools to have your customized OS.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker